# Teams' 'Contact support' button not visible in smaller screens

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, design

There's a floating button 'Contact support' on the bottom right of all Teams pages, which links to a ['Submit a ticket' page](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/tickets/new).

[image]

However, on smaller screen widths, it's gone entirely. I'm not sure if this is by design?

Comment: For me, the page isn't responsive even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your report and sorry for the delay! This is indeed a bug that will be fixed with our next production build.